# Powershell File search by date, display date and path info, cannot export CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-4.0

I'm new to Powershell and I have gotten my batch file to work to output the results to the screen. I want the file exported as a CSV in order to be able to get it into an Excel file sortable by Directory, then date.

I can get the `Out-File` command to write a basic file, but the CSV output doesn't seem to want to work right. I only get a CSV file with the `Length` of each record.

Can anyone help?   Thanks in advance.

---

This is what I tried:

```
#--Change the name with directory you want to visit --#    
$dir_to_look="E:\xPression\CustomerData\xPressionECR\*\XMLDATA"    

#--You may change the number of days of your choice --#   
$TwoDays=$(Get-Date).AddDays(-2)    

Remove-Item E:\xPression\CustomerData\xPressionECR\ReportOutput\Report.csv

#--Find the files which are modified or created within last 2 days --#    
Get-Childitem $dir_to_look *.xml  -Recurse | `   
        where-object {!($_.psiscontainer)} | `   
        where { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $TwoDays } | `   
        ForEach-Object {  "$($_.LastWriteTime) , $($_.Fullname)"| Out-File -LiteralPath E:\xPression\CustomerData\xPressionECR\ReportOutput\Report.csv -Append}
```

Comment: Given that you use `$_.psiscontainer`, can we assume you are limited to Powershell-v2? It would help if you would add your Powershell-Version as a tag :)

Comment: My version info:   PSVersion                      4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two helpfull functions that you should take a closer look at are `Select-Object` and `Export-Csv`.

If you want to create .csv File that contains two rows consisting of the `LastWriteTime` and the `FullName` you can do it like this:

```
Get-Childitem $dir_to_look *.xml  -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $TwoDays } | Select-Object LastWriteTime, FullName | Export-Csv -LiteralPath "E:\xPression\CustomerData\xPressionECR\ReportOutput\Report.csv "
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked like a charm.   Have a great day!

Comment: @RDavidson Glad I could help! When answers help you, you can vote them up to show other people that they are good. Also when a question of yours was answered you can mark one answer as correct, this way the question isn't displayed as open. Ref. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Export-Csv not Out-File at the end of your pipeline. Your code would become:

```
Get-Childitem $dir_to_look *.xml -Recurse  -File | 
where LastWriteTime -gt $TwoDays  | 
select Fullname, LastWriteTime |
Export-Csv -Path E:\xPression\CustomerData\xPressionECR\ReportOutput\Report.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You don't need to test for PSisContainer if you use the -File parameter on Get-ChildItem. You can use select to just pass the two propertyies your interested in and then output to a csv file.  You also don't need the ` after the pipeline symbol at the end of your second where statement.  A pipeline symbol at the end of a line is automatically a line continuation marker.

Hope this answers your question. happy to follow up if there's anything else you weant to ask about this code.